# How to create a login system without using a database?

Tags: android, database

I want to create an app for my college, and I've already added some functions to it, like "Maps of College", "Scenery of Campus", etc. Now I want that students can check their mailboxes of University and see their scores. 
 My college already has a website in which we can login with our college account. So I was wondering is their a way to create a login page without using any database. The username and password users passed on the phone may be sent to the website or somewhere, and they can see their scores automatically on my app.
 I have already learned something about database, MySQL. But the data should be kept by the university, so maybe I don't have to create my own database.
 I'm really new to android, may you don't laugh at my stupid question.
 Just give some guide, plz!

Comment: you want to be able to get the information from the student without using the university database? no.

Comment: No, I want to be able to get the information directly from the university's database without creating my own database. I just don't know how to access the database of my university.

Comment: you cant access the login information of your college without any sort of API or their permission. What you want to accomplish can not work without that.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it is better to understand how login system works.

A login generally requires the user to enter two pieces of information, first a user name and then a password. When attempting to log into a system, the user names and passwords entered by the potential user are compared with data contained in special databases on the system.

With that being said, you need to have users' data stored in a database through which you can programmatically compare users' input to grand them access into a particular system.

The other option would be to have access to your university's website API. This way, you can retrieve all users' data from your university's database and use it instead. Think about how so many services use your google or facebook login ?

I hope this helps clear out some blur !

Comment: Actually I've learned something about the login system, and I have created a small database myself. The problem is the database of username and password is kept by the university which I cannot access, and I see no API in the website of my college.

Comment: Nice ! The only way to use their credentials is to have access to that database somehow...